# How to get max of a column based on other columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following table,

| Name | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | NY | 1 |
| Tom | NY | 2 |
| Tom | NY | 4 |
| James | NY | 1 |
| James | NY | 2 |
| Tony | DC | 1 |
| Tony | DC | 2 |

I want to find the total value city-wise, however for each Name only their maximum value must be taken. So for this table I should get,

| City | Value |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 6 |
| DC | 2 |

I have tried using various methods using dyplr but none seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your dataset is called df1:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(City, Name) %>% slice_max(Value, with_ties = FALSE) %>% ungroup() %>% select(City, Value) %>% group_by(City) %>% summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```

Comment: Perhaps `slice_max(Value, with_ties = FALSE)` to prevent double-counts where a name has tied max value in a city.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
  distinct(Name, City, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))

#  City  Value
#  <chr> <int>
#1 DC        2
#2 NY        6
```

Comment: What if there are multiple value columns and I need a summarized dataframe with maximum of each value columns by the city

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach in one line:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[df[, .I[which.max(Value)], by=c("Name", "City")]$V1][, sum(Value), by=City]
```

**Output**

```
   City V1
1:   NY  6
2:   DC  2
```

**base R**

```
aggregate(Value ~ City, merge(aggregate(Value ~ Name + City, data=df, max), df, all.x=T), sum)

  City Value
1   DC     2
2   NY     6
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(
  Name = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "James", "James",
           "Tony", "Tony"),
  City = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "DC",
           "DC"),
  Value = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```